# Female OBD2 Connector

Tags: connector, obd

Does anyone know what's this exact connector:

[image]

I got it from [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/OBD2-OBD-II-OBD-2-16-Pin-Connector-Female-Diagnostic-Tool-OBD-Connector-Plug-Shell-Terminal/32694213215.html), but I lost these metal connectors, and I was hoping to find them at DigiKey or similar sites, but the one that I was able to find is for slightly different connector, female obd2 connector which you can find there which looks like this, and that one does not fit into the socket that I have from AliExpress (which I need):

[image]

Comment: These are called "contacts", and you should find them along with the housing.

Comment: I have posted the link, but there is no info about these contacts there

Comment: https://www.mouser.de/Alle-Hersteller/_/N-0?Keyword=obd+connector&FS=True